# Understanding the LLVM cast instruction

Tags: casting, llvm

Suppose I have an two llvm value pointers x and y, with x being a double and y a signed integer. And I wish to cast y to x's type. I'd have to do

```
y = builder.CreateCast(Instruction::SIToFP, y, x->getType());
```

Or equivalently

```
y = builder.CreateCast(Instruction::SIToFP, y, Type::getDoubleTy(context));
```

*Why does one have to explicitly specify the instruction? which in this case is `Instruction::SIToFP`, instead of just specifying the value to be casted and the destination type*. This seems redundant to me as one would have to know in advance the types of x and y to specify the right instruction.

Comment: Only the SIToFP specifies that you want to treat y as a *signed* integer. UIToFP would also cast the same bit pattern to FP, but treat y as unsigned. There are quite a few other cases where the choice of how to cast isn't trivial.

Comment: @arnt Still don't understand why we'll always have to specify how we *want y to be treated*. Could there be a default cast instruction where, say the type of y could be just be inferred?

Comment: Of course it could, but what should the default do and what would be the point? LLVM's target audience is compilers, and a compiler is bound by a source language's specified casting rules. What use does a compiler have for some nontrivial cast operation that doesn't match the source language?

Comment: @arnt I think you've misunderstood my problem. What's the use specifying the instruction `Instruction:SIToFP` and then still specifying the target type, when the instruction clearly indicates a cast to float??? Plus why can llvm not just do a `y->getType()` under the hood ?? **so it can generate the appropriate instruction corresponding to this type** which in this case is a signed integer. I think this is independent of the source language's casting rules.

Comment: LLVM offers two casts from int to FP, SIToFP and UIToFP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot determine whether y is a signed or unsigned integer without passing it explicitly, because LLVM's integer types are neither signed nor unsigned: they represent fixed-width bit vector operations and it is *operations* over that type which are either signed or unsigned. This is fairly standard when reasoning close to the machine level because the machine sees integers the same way. It thus makes it easier for LLVM to reason about program optimizations, one of its principle design goals.